# JSON.stringify not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am trying to parse some form data to produce JSON data to send in an ajax request. The following HTML is an oversimplified version of my code. I'm using APS.Net MVC4 and my rendered view produces the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="test-class" data-my-attribute="1"></div>
<div class="test-class" data-my-attribute="2"></div>
<div class="test-class" data-my-attribute="3"></div>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        jsonObj = [];
        $(".test-class").each(function () {
            var myAttribute = $(this).data('my-attribute');
            item = {}
            item["MyAttribute"] = myAttribute;
            jsonObj.push(item);
        });
        var data = { SomeOtherData: 1234, MyAttribs: jsonObj };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome the output in the console is output as expected ...

```
{
    "SomeOtherData": 1234,
    "MyAttribs": [{
        "MyAttribute": 1
    }, {
        "MyAttribute": 2
    }, {
        "MyAttribute": 3
    }]
}
```

... but in IE the objects come out as null ...

```
{
    "SomeOtherData": 1234,
    "MyAttribs": [null, null, null]
}
```

I've had a look around and found some other questions that recommend checking that the page has `<!DOCTYPE html>` in it (which it does) and that doesn't seem to have any effect. I've also read that this should work in from IE8 onward so not sure what's happening.

1. Does anyone know why the objects are appearing as nulls in IE?
2. What is the best cross-browser solution to this?

Thanks,
Gavin

Comment: Try `console.dir(jsonObj)`. What does it output?

Comment: Hi @Teemu, I put a debugger just before the console.log statement and verified that the jsonObj all looks fine. It's jQuery that is dealing with the data- attributes and that is working fine.

Comment: You could try one of the backfilling libraries like [json3](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/). This should hopefully produce a consistent result.

Comment: @Pavlo, ran the `console.dir(jsonObj)` and get:   `function item() {     [native code] } , function item() {     [native code] } , function item() {     [native code] }  {
 0 :  function item() {     [native code] } ,
 1 :  function item() {     [native code] } ,
 2 :  function item() {     [native code] } 
}`

Comment: @GavinSutherland Yep, I just realized it, that's why I removed the comment.

Comment: Is it in compatibility mode?

Comment: Though this is not a solution, but please use `var item = {}`  instead of `item = {}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only weird thing I see is that:

```
  item = {}
```

Should be:

```
  var item = {}; // 'var' and semicolon
```

Sometimes IE is quite strict..

Comment: Looks like IE has a native function called `item`.

Comment: You probably saved me from hours of frustration! Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

on my case use as @palvo sayed console.dir(obj)

other alternative is JSON2 from [douglascrockford](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29914468)